# Is it bad to keep code in View code behind?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've tried to read article [WPF/Silverlight: Step By Step Guide to MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/StepByStepGuideToMVVM.aspx) but I can not understand it completely.

However I've noticied such guideline:

> That is your View.xaml.cs that is supposed to have almost no code.

How should I fix my code below? Should I extract my WCF code to some another place? Thanks.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChannelFactory<IManagementConsole> pipeFactory =
                new ChannelFactory<IManagementConsole>(
                    new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                    new EndpointAddress(
                        "net.pipe://localhost/PipeManagementConsole"));

        IManagementConsole pipeProxy =
          pipeFactory.CreateChannel();

        List<ConsoleData> datas = new List<ConsoleData>();
        foreach (StrategyDescriptor sd in pipeProxy.GetStrategies())
        {
            datas.Add(pipeProxy.GetData(sd.Id));
        }
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = datas;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you have WCF code in a view? This looks like very bad design...

Comment: Looks to be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878610/why-keep-code-behind-clean-and-do-everything-in-xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is bad practice especially from the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) perspectives.

Extract all business logic into the *ServiceViewModel* class, in View just set instance of ViewModel to DataContext:

```cs
 public MainWindow()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.DataContext = new ServiceViewModel();
 }
```

If you have an other class/window which is instantiate this Window you should set ViewModel within it. For instance:

```cs
MyWindow childWindow = new MyWindow();
childWindow.DataContext = new ServiceViewModel();
```

So now you can see MVVM in action, in MainWindow XAML file you can use bindings like below:

```xml
<!-- Considering that ServiceViewModel has 
     public string ServiceName property 
 -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ServiceName}" />

<!-- Considering that ServiceViewModel has
     public List<ConsoleData> DataItems property
 -->
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}" />
```

In this way your logic stay in ViewModel and decoupled from View.

PS:

I would suggest using `ObservableCollection<ConsoleData>` for ConsoleData list, benefits are: ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx))

> **ObservableCollection Class**
>
> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
>   items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: thanks, can I set DataContext in xaml and so eliminate this last line of code? How to implement ServiceViewModel? link to corresponding documentation is welcome.

Comment: @javapowered : see just updated answer, basically your ViewModel should expose `ObservableCollection<ConsoleData> DataItems` then just bind it in XAML like shown in answer

Comment: Yes, you can set the DataContext in XAML.  You'll need to add a namespace reference and create an instance of the ViewModel class in the Resources section.  Then you an bind the DataContext to that resource.